# Typing a recursive Immutable js Record in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, immutable.js

I am trying to represent a tree-like data structure using immutable js and typescript. Right now, I am using normal vanilla js objects to represent the nodes in the tree. Here is the type signature.

```js
type NodeType = {
    value: string
    children: List<NodeType>
}
```

I want to convert this to a Record, but I am confused about how to do this. If I just to the obvious:

```js
const defaultValues: NodeType = {
    value: "foo",
    children: List()
}
const NodeRecord = Record(defaultValues)
```

...then it will be fine at the top level, but it will expect the children to be of type `NodeType` rather than `RecordOf(NodeType)`.

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are running into? Because as far as I can tell your code works just as you expect: https://tsplay.dev/N5EpPN

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example in the docs](https://immutable-js.com/docs/latest@main/Record/) that might be helpful.
The way you wrote it, your NodeType only describes *the default values*, but not a `Record`.

```
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable';

// Use RecordFactory<TProps> for defining new Record factory functions.
type NodeTypeProps = { 
  value: string
  children: List<RecordOf<NodeTypeProps>>
};
const defaultValues: NodeTypeProps = { value: "meh" };
const makeNodeType: RecordFactory<NodeTypeProps> = Record(defaultValues);

type NodeType = RecordOf<NodeTypeProps>;
const someNodeType: NodeType = makeNodeType({ value: "some" });
```

Disclaimer: I never used Immutable with TS and know it's sometime a bit painful. Since the type is recursive, there might be extra steps involved to make the TS compiler happy